# Postgresql 14.6 going under recovery mode after some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am facing a weird issue regarding my PostgreSQL 14.6 which is running on ubuntu 20.
Using Ruby on Rails framework also using pgbouncer Didn't understand why it's happening?

Our application must have at least 250 pools because sometimes we run more than 300 threads for several hours or one day. While this type of job is running, the database sometimes goes into recovery mode and terminates all connections. Then after 1 or 2 seconds, everything goes back to normal. But the background services have a problem. I don't know why sometimes this postgresql database goes into recovery mode.

System ram is 48GB I've increased max connections based on How to increase the max connections in postgres? So currently shared_buffers = 8192MB and kernel.shmmax=1342177280

Also tried to fix any PostgreSQL configured settings using [postgresqltuner](https://github.com/jfcoz/postgresqltuner).

As I am running background jobs in ruby on rails which involves over 100 concurrent threads. The database goes into recovery mode and stops that background job.
Any suggestion to avoid the database recovery mode issue?

```
# pgbouncer.ini
[databases]
app_production = host=localhost dbname=app_production port=5432

[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
listen_port = 16432
auth_file = userlist.txt
logfile = pgbouncer.log
pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
admin_users = appuser
max_client_conn = 1000
default_pool_size = 1000
```

```
# database.yml
production:
      adapter: postgresql
      host: 127.0.0.1
      database: app_production
      username: appuser
      password: defaultpassword
      encoding: unicode
      pool: 1000
      port: 16432
```

```
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: web
# Total Memory (RAM): 48 GB
# CPUs num: 12
# Connections num: 1000
# Data Storage: hdd

max_connections = 1000
shared_buffers = 12GB
effective_cache_size = 36GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 3145kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 12
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 12
```

Comment: `the database sometimes goes into recovery mode and terminates all connections` can you show the logs when this is happening?

Comment: appuser@app_production LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

Comment: That's not a problem on the server end

Comment: 2023-02-08 07:05:06.269 UTC [4655] root@production LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2023-02-08 07:05:06.269 UTC [4653] root@production LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2023-02-08 07:05:06.269 UTC [4652] root@production LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2023-02-08 07:05:06.269 UTC [4654] root@production LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

Comment: You need to look at the part of the log that pertains to it going into recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.
ok, i will try to find out the correct logs.

Actually, we are using these queries massively, about 500,000 per session, do you have any idea on how to adjust them?

Comment: HI Thank you for helping,

here are some of the queries we are using, we are doing about 500k queries every run, unless it stops us with the log error

This is currently what i see in our logs, can you direct me to where i can find further logs into the problem?

root@production LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

Below are some sample of our queries we making to postgesql .